# how do I SELECT all from multiple tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 identical tables (same column count and column names) in my database which are supposed to provide content in 3 languages, user-preferred languages are passed as an url parameter. This is how I query for one table:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news_en WHERE time > $from"; 

$result = $conn->query ( $sql );
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
        echo "Post Title: " . $row ["title"] . "<br>" . "Post Text: " . $row ["article"] . "<br> " . "Time: " . $row ["time"] . "<br>" . "Image: " . "<a href=" . $row ["image"] . ">click for post image</a><br>" . "Source: " . $row ["source"] . "<br><br>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
```

This query is executed correctly. However, when I try to do it for 3 available languages

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM news_en, news_de, news_ru WHERE time > $from";
```

I am getting the error:

```
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\..... on line 54
 0 results
```

line 54 is

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
```

so I assume the query is not executed correctly. But if I directly execute the same query by going to `SQL` in `phpMyAdmin` it gives correct results from all the 3 tables.

What am doing wrong in my php?

Comment: That seems like a bad database design to have as many tables as many languages you would like to support with the same scheme. Why don't you have only 1 table with a column storing the language info?

Comment: @CMate thats a good idea, thanks. Well, I've just started to work with back-end development and since I know I will only have 3 languages and those tables are quite small I can use 3 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql is confused when you select columns with same name. The solution is to use Alias.

```
$sql = "SELECT en.col1 AS col1en, en.col2 AS col2en, de.col1 AS col1de, de.col2 AS col2de, ru.col1 AS col1ru, ru.col2 AS col2ru
 FROM news_en AS en, news_de AS de, news_ru AS ru WHERE time > $from";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you certainly need to have a look into database design!

A better databse design would be to save all language strings within a single table and add an additional column containing the language information.

Your query does not work at the moment as a SELECT query always returns result objects of similar type. Selecting from different tables at the same time does not guarantee such consistent result objects as the tables might have different columns.